# Does any small enough circle around a point of a curve, intersects it at exactly two points?

Tags: curves, plane-curves, fractals

If we choose any point of a line, a parabola, a circle, a sinusoidal curve etc, as a center of a circle of radius r, then there is a distance d such that, if r<d, the circle intersects the curve at exactly two points. I wonder if this is true for any plane curve that does not intersect it self. Fractal curves come to mind, that may provide a counter example, but I can not prove it. Space-filling curves also come to mind, but I am no sure they fulfill the definition of a simple curve (not self-intersecting). In any case, if we exclude space filling curves, are there any examples of simple plane curve, either closed, or open that tends to infinity from both directions, which has points such that, any circle around them, however small, could intersect the curve in more than two points?

---

Edit: What about fractal curves like Koch snowflake, Cesàro fractal, Fibonacci word fractal, Minkowski sausage etc.

Comment: The topologist's sine curve will be a counter example. You just need to wrap it around so that the vertical $x=0$ line becomes part of the curve. I think this variant is also called Warsaw circle. Btw, space filling curves are rarely injective. Only in the trivial case of intervals.

Comment: The answer depends on the regularity of the curve. Smooth? Only continuous?

Comment: @coudy Only continuous.

Comment: The existence of a circle that intersects exactly at two points a given curve is studied in the monograph N. I. Muskhelishvili,  - Singular Integral Equations_ Boundary Problems of Function Theory and Their Application to Mathematical Physics -Dover Publications, translation edited by J.R.M. Radok, 1953, on pages 424-425.

Comment: Just saw a similar theorem in a book  Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi - Complex analysis-Princeton University Press (2003), page 362.

Comment: @zkutch The theorems you are mentioning in both your references are about smooth curves. I understand that what I ask is true for all smooth simple curves (non self-intersecting and differentiable everywhere) with non zero derivatives, but it is not true for every curve what so ever, as coudy has already explained. I was hoping for more examples of (simple) curves that make it not true (I am looking for an easy way to present this conclusion, understandable by a student) and also, what is the case with fractal curves.

Comment: @Aris Makrides. It may be interesting for you that in the book from the first comment, the case of a piecewise smooth curve is also considered and the theorem is preserved in corner points, other than casps. So, possibly, considering cuspidal points can be way to construct simple example.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for a $C^1$ curve with non-zero derivative at all points. This comes from the fact that such a curve is locally diffeomorphic to a segment. This can be proven using the inverse function theorem or the [constant rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem).

This is false for $C^0$ curves, or even for $C^1$ curves with a point with zero derivative. The curve may spiral around the point with zero derivative. Let make the spiral a bit square, and since a circle intersects a square in four points when they have the same centers and close diameter, you will have more than two intersection points. Here is a rough sketch. with the first bold curve spiraling to the point of zero derivative, and the lighter curve going away from it. Both meet at a point where the derivative is zero.

[image: spiraling curve]

Finally, it can be shown using the Baire category theorem, that a generic continuous curve that intersect any segment not restricted to a point will intersect it infinitely many times. Such curve will also intersect a circle infinitely many times. This is a bit unintuitive if you have never heard of the Baire category theorem.